# How to find the PHP file which prints an HTML element with a certain selector?

Tags: files, search, text, pattern-matching

I store my MediaWiki 1.36.1 website with Skin:Timeless on NameCheap with a shared hosting environment with Cpanel file manager and SSH shell access.

In my website, there is a certain footer element with the following CSS ID:

```
footer-info-lastmod
```

I have already prevented this element from being printed by commenting the command which prints it:

```
// 'lastmod' => !$useCredits ? $this->lastModified() : null,
```

But still, how could I find the PHP file which prints the HTML element with **that CSS ID** is available?

### Update based on comment

```bsh
cd web_application_root
grep -rn footer-info-lastmod .
```

Brought:

```bsh
./extensions/VisualEditor/modules/ve-mw/init/targets/ve.init.mw.DesktopArticleTarget.js:1368:     if ( !$( '#footer-info-lastmod' ).length ) {
./extensions/VisualEditor/modules/ve-mw/init/targets/ve.init.mw.DesktopArticleTarget.js:1370:     $( '<li>' ).attr( 'id', 'footer-info-lastmod' )
./extensions/VisualEditor/modules/ve-mw/init/targets/ve.init.mw.DesktopArticleTarget.js:1375:     $( '#footer-info-lastmod' ).html( ' ' + mw.msg(
```

Comment: What have you tried? `grep -rn footer-info-lastmod /path/to/server/root` will likely turn up all the files with that id in it; that will also include the css files themselves, maybe others but if it's php file that's responsible (rather than javascript or something else), it'll likely be listed. I guess possible the ids are constructed piecemeal and then this won't find it.

Comment: @frabjous I didn't try anything because I don't know a command to search a file with a text but I shared what I did do to prevent the print of this element. Anyway if I understand you correctly you say that it might be the case that the CSS ID is actually constructed from two or more PHP files? That's an awful way to print a selector, I'd say...

Comment: That's possible, but unlikely. Try the command I suggested and see what happens. If your goal is just to make these elements disappear from the page, you could also consider just adding `display: none;` to the css.

Comment: @frabjous thank you, I was under too much stress to search for a command but had to do so myself. Thanks to you I have found a command. I have updated the question.

Comment: @frabjous yes, I avoid hiding things with `display: none;` due to SEO reasons, thank you a lot !!!

Comment: "Which lines in this large program contribute a particular feature to its output" is a kind of big topic. In some programs it can be very obvious, whereas others can conceal it in layers of calculations, which pull information from multiple places.